Can select the className of a component through the another component in React?
I have two components of Button and Icon, and define as follows:
Button.tsx

import { forwardRef, ElementType } from "react";
import { Icon } from "../Icon";
import { ButtonProps } from "./props.interfaces";
import classNames from "./Button.module.scss";
import React from "react";

const Button = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>((props, ref) => {
    const { rightIcon, leftIcon, type, children, tagName, centerIcon, variant, color, size = "md" } = props;
    const Component: ElementType = (tagName || "span") as ElementType;
    const otherProps = { ...props };

    
    return (
        <Component ref={ref} {...otherProps} type={type}>
            {rightIcon && <Icon iconName={rightIcon} className="ml-xs btn-icon" />}
            {centerIcon ? <Icon iconName={centerIcon} className="btn-icon" /> : <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>}
            {leftIcon && <Icon iconName={leftIcon} className="mr-xs btn-icon" />}
        </Component>
    );
});

Button.displayName = "rh-button";
export default Button;


And Icon component  as "
import { forwardRef } from "react";
import { IconProps } from "./props.interface";
import getClassnames from "../../utils/getClassnames";
const Icon = forwardRef<HTMLElement, IconProps>((props, ref) => {
    const { iconName, className } = props;
    return <i {...props} ref={ref} className={getClassnames(`${className}`, `icon-${iconName}`)}></i>;
});

export default Icon;

I want to select the .btn-icon class that has been defined as prop through the Button.tsx component.
I have select the btn-icon class inside of button.scss as follows:

.btn {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    user-select: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: $radius-xs;
    color: $basic-25;
    background-color: $primary-500;
    text-decoration: none;

    > i {
        &.btn-icon {
            width: 18px !important;
            height: 18px !important;
        }
    }
}

But it does not affect on btn-icon class of i tag. However, when I just select the i without class of btn-icon. the style works!.
How can solve it ?
